# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected for multi column "in" statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a query for selecting the distinct caller from TSN2 table with having the maximum amount of weight. For such query I  have oracle sql query like this:

```
select * from dbo.TSN2 
where (caller,weight) in 
    (select caller,max(cast(weight as float))
    from dbo.TSN2 
    group by caller);
```

Unfortunately such query gave me "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected" error in mssql. Would you please tell me what same mssql query works for me?

Comment: `where (caller,weight) in (select ...)` is fully legal in Oracle, but probably is not allowed in mssql.

Answer (score 1):

non boolean type occurs in here (caller,weight) IN ... . You cant use multiple fields before IN function. it can only check 1 value is in an table or not.

This question does not need a nested sql query.

```
select caller,max(cast(weight as float)), other fields
from dbo.TSN2 
group by caller
```

This returns; Each caller id and its maximum weight.
If you want to see Each distinct caller info with their max weight. This query is enough.

But if, you really want to use nested query. You need to try different aproach. However this is not a very nice solution to that.

```
select * //from dbo.TSN2 (you dont need to include this again if it is in the subquery)
where 
    caller in 
    (select caller 
    from dbo.TSN2 
    group by caller)
    AND 
    weight in 
    (select max(cast(weight as float))
    from dbo.TSN2 
    group by caller);
```

which is very dum. So go for the first query you dont need to use nested queries.

Comment: Documentation says the opposite, at least in Oracle. And, btw, your query is not equivalent with the OP. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21642/search.htm#TTSQL262

Comment: The SQL standard allows tuple comparison with `IN`. So `(a,b) in (select c,d ...)` **is** valid SQL and Oracle (amongst others) *does* support this. However SQL Server does not.

Comment: <left> IN <right> Sorry then the problem is right side. in the right side try to print 1 field . not both CALLER , MAX(foo). if the left side is okey then it must be the right side.because (a,b) IN {(x1,y1)(x2,y2)(x3,y3)(x4,y4)...} doesnt seem like a function that returns boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Below Query will help you

```
SELECT DISTINCT q.* FROM
  (select caller,max(cast(weight as float)) AS Weight
     from dbo.TSN2 
     group by caller) p 
  INNER JOIN dbo.TSN2  q
  ON p.caller = q.caller AND cast(p.weight as float) = cast(q.weight as float)
```